# Could not load NIB in bundle error

Tags: ios, xcode, parsing, storyboard, xib

I am setting up parse and have some problems. I am using a storyboard to do this.  However I am getting a error saying

```
2014-04-08 23:11:59.802 ParseStarterProject[5729:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/user/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1-64/Applications/CCA0F113-88E5-4181-A5A0-77841C12939E/ParseStarterProject.app> (loaded)' with name 'MainWindow''
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102d1f495 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010258a99e objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102d1f2ad +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
    3   UIKit                               0x0000000101392742 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 775
    4   UIKit                               0x00000001013942a0 -[NSBundle(UINSBundleAdditions) loadNibNamed:owner:options:] + 138
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010113760d -[UIApplication _loadMainNibFileNamed:bundle:] + 42
    6   UIKit                               0x000000010113693e -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 454
    7   UIKit                               0x0000000101147d4c -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 3189
    8   UIKit                               0x0000000101148216 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 79
    9   UIKit                               0x0000000101138086 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 578
    10  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000102c4c71a _PurpleEventCallback + 762
    11  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000102c4c1e1 PurpleEventCallback + 35
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102ca1679 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 41
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102ca144e __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 478
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102cca903 __CFRunLoopRun + 1939
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102cc9d83 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    16  UIKit                               0x00000001011362e1 -[UIApplication _run] + 609
    17  UIKit                               0x0000000101137e33 UIApplicationMain + 1010
    18  ParseStarterProject                 0x0000000100002f83 main + 115
    19  ParseStarterProject                 0x0000000100001fd4 start + 52
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Why am I getting this, and are there possible fixes?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the error message and the "MainWindow". I guess, you deleted a UIWindow from the storyboard, which is still referenced in you AppDelegate.

Could you validate this by checking, whether there is some Zombie-reference of a MainWindow-Class?

In case you added a Storyboard for being new main interface:

Please make sure, you also set this new Storyboard as new Main Interface in your Build target. Herefore, go to your xCode-Project file and select the build target. In the General tab set the "Main Interface" to match your new storyboard
[image]

Comment: I do have a piece of code saying `@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;` and     
    `self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];`

Comment: Is the window referenced in the Storyboard - as it is already as IBOutlet set? In case it is: did you change this reference in the storyboard at any time?

Comment: Did you rename the storyboard?

Comment: I have deleted the nib and added a storyboard

Comment: Please make sure, you also set this new Storyboard as new Main Interface in your Build target. Herefore, go to your xCode-Project file and select the build target. In the General tab set the "Main Interface" to match your new storyboard